# A possible interpretation of that island in movie

Tags: life-of-pi

A possible interpretation of that island in movie (Life Of A Pie)

may be he was dreaming about that island ...... before this scene he mentions that he was unable to distinguish between reality and his dream ......maybe this island is one of the creations of his own dream .....as he believed lord vishnu - the supreme soul , the source of everything - sleeps floating on the cosmic ocean .....so he was dreaming about an island , of the shape of lord vishnu ,is there to save him from all the pain and agony he is going through .....thats how he was raised in his childhood that GOD is always there to help you .....maybe his sub conscious mind was playing with him by fantasizing all these and giving him a hope to live

Comment: You will want to add your interpretation as an answer to [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8852/what-would-be-the-equivalent-of-the-carnivorous-island).

Comment: Where is the question?